# How to change this code to write to stdout instead?

Tags: c, linux, file-io, stdout

I'm trying to change this to print to the terminal screen instead of a file. So I'm trying to print to stdout.

```
char    buf;    
int s, n;       
char filename[LINELEN];
char *recfile = "recfile.txt";
FILE *finp;

fflush(NULL);
while(buf != EOF)
{
    fflush(finp);
    if (read(s, &buf, 1) < 0) {
        printf("\terror in recieving file\n");
    }
    if(buf != EOF)
    (void) fputc(buf, finp);
}
fclose(finp);
close(s);
```

I tried to make this change.

```
finp = freopen("/dev/null","w+", stdout);
```

Everything in linux is a file, right? So why didn't that work?

Comment: I don't think you're showing all of the code.  But why not just call `putc()` instead of `fputc()`?  If you want output to go on `stout`, it seems like redirecting it to `/dev/null` isn't a very good idea...

Comment: *I'm trying to ... print to the terminal screen* Why do you think `freopen("/dev/null","w+", stdout)` would reassociate `stdout` to the terminal?

Comment: This program fragment almost certainly doesn't work for several reasons. We need to see _all_ of the source code, and preferably an example of the input file it is trying to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't it be `fputc(buf, stdout);`?

Answer (score 1):

You open `/dev/null` and redirect stdout to it, but writing a a character to `/dev/null` ignores it. freopen() redirects `stdout` to the file `/dev/null` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

There are several other problems with that program.

Reading the file using:

```
if (read(s, &buf, 1) < 0) ...
```

does not put an EOF value into buf, so

```
if(buf != EOF)
```

and

```
while(buf != EOF)
```

will not terminate when it has reached the end of file.

if `buf` gets the character value `0xFF` put into it, then that value will be sign-extended, and be mistaken for `EOF`.

`read` signals end of file by returning 0.

`s` is not properly initialsed, so it may be unpredictable while file descriptor it will read.

Comment: @Dave - why have you edited the text of my answer, and appear to have replaced every character with exactly the same character, i.e. made no changes that I can see, except for the HTH?

Comment: Mostly because I accidentally downvoted this, but it was locked, so I had to edit to undownvote. Aside from that, HTH is usually not stackoverflow form, and  using the 4 space code blocks enables syntax highlighting.

Comment: @Dave - thanks for de-downvoting me!-) Also thanks for the HTH tip, I use it, and I've seen it used, so I did not know. I'll go look to see what a "4 space block" is, I've been using the {} command to do highlighting.